# How to find maxima or minima for the given function

Tags: derivatives

How to find maxima or minima for this function $F$

$F=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 5x_{i}^{3}+2x_{i}+6$

If it is possible to find maxima or minima for this function, what is the double derivative of the function else why not possible to find the derivative

Comment: Is $f$ a function of several variables, i.e. $f(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$. If not,  where is $x$ on the $R.H.S$. Would you please explain what is the relation between $x$ and $x_i$s.

Comment: I think now the question is meaningful

Comment: Assuming $n$ to be varying, the sum goes to $\infty$ when $n \to \infty$. Minima occurs at $n=1$

Comment: what if n can never be infinity, n interval is [5,100]